# Not able to convert string to int. Error msg: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following c# code which should output `fee_paid_int` as `'20'` and `total_student_int` as `'30'` how ever I am receiving the following error when I debug the code on `int fee_paid_int = Convert.ToInt32(fee_paid_string.Trim());`

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

## C#

```
//Total Student's - Not counting Graduated, Withdrawn or Temporarily Withdrawn
DataView t_stu = (DataView)total_students_count.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    foreach (DataRowView t_stu_sql in t_stu)
    {
        total_students_count_label.Text = "Total Current Students: <b>" + t_stu_sql["total_students"].ToString() + "</b><p></p>";
    }

// Total Fee's Paid to Date
DataView f_paid = (DataView)fees_paid_count.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    foreach (DataRowView fee_paid_sql in f_paid)
    {
        fees_paid_count_label.Text = "Total Fee's Paid to date: <b>" + fee_paid_sql["fee_paid"].ToString() + "</b><p></p>";
    }

int fee_paid_int = Convert.ToInt32(total_students_count_label.Text.Trim());
int total_student_int = Convert.ToInt32(fees_paid_count_label.Text.Trim());
int fee_paid_percent = (int)Math.Round((double)(100 * fee_paid_int) / total_student_int);
fee_paid_percent_label.Text = "Total Percent of Student's who have fully paid their Tution Fee to date " + fee_paid_percent + "%";
```

`int fee_paid_percent` should equal `66.66`, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
total_students_count_label.Text = "Total Current Students: <b>" +
 t_stu_sql["total_students"].ToString() + "</b><p></p>";
```

The contents of this control cannot be converted to int because this contains non-numeric and non-integer contents..

you may need to revise this to change total_students_count_label.Text to contain only numbers - in your case... it should be

```
total_students_count_label.Text = t_stu_sql["total_students"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line in your code.

```
//Total Student's - Not counting Graduated, Withdrawn or Temporarily Withdrawn
DataView t_stu =   (DataView)total_students_count.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
foreach (DataRowView t_stu_sql in t_stu)
{
    total_students_count_label.Text = t_stu_sql["total_students"].ToString();
}

  // Total Fee's Paid to Date
DataView f_paid = (DataView)fees_paid_count.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
foreach (DataRowView fee_paid_sql in f_paid)
{
    fees_paid_count_label.Text = fee_paid_sql["fee_paid"].ToString(); 
}

int fee_paid_int = Convert.ToInt32(total_students_count_label.Text.Trim());
int total_student_int = Convert.ToInt32(fees_paid_count_label.Text.Trim());
int fee_paid_percent = (int)Math.Round((double)(100 * fee_paid_int) /    total_student_int);
fee_paid_percent_label.Text = "Total Percent of Student's who have fully paid their Tution Fee to date " + fee_paid_percent + "%";
```

Comment: The variables such as 't_stu_sql' would not exist in this context as they are located within the foreach statement.